# How to set up Xdebug profiling on PHP 7.2 & PHP-FPM

Tags: xdebug, fpm

I'm trying to do some PHP profiling using Xdebug on a local environment. I'm running Ubuntu 22.04

I'm using PHP-FPM to run PHP v7.2 through a virtualhost.

`php -v` outputs

```
Zend Engine v4.1.7, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.7, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.1.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by Derick Rethans
```

On /tmp/xdebug I've run

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER /tmp/xdebug
```

At the bottom of my `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini`  & `/etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini` files I've put:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=xdebug
xdebug.output_dir = /tmp/xdebug
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.mode=develop,trace,profile
```

I then run

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

The enabled Xdebug features are showing up in `phpinfo()` in my main /localhost/ directory (using PHP 8.*), but not in the one using PHP 7.2

In my virtualhost .conf file I'm setting the PHP version like (I'm including this because I'm not sure if I need to do anything in this .conf file or not)

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
        # For Apache version 2.4.10 and above, use SetHandler to run PHP as a fastCGI process server
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
</FilesMatch>
```

The image below shows `phpinfo()` picking up my Xdebug settings on PHP 8.*; the directory using PHP 7.2 shows no Xdebug settings enabled.

[image: XDEBUG FEATURES]

**My question(s) / Issues**:

- How do I get PHP 7.2 to recognize my Xdebug settings?
- How do I get Xdebug to output profile files to /tmp/xdebug? (I plan to use Webgrind)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm using PHP-FPM to run PHP v7.2

PHP 7.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php), so please upgrade to at least PHP 7.4, but preferably PHP 8.0 or 8.1.

> the directory using PHP 7.2 shows no Xdebug settings enabled.

- Make sure that you edit the right `php.ini` file — the `xdebug_info()` and `phpinfo()` sections should show which files it used.
- Did you restart your PHP 7.2 PHP-FPM as well? The `systemctl restart` line for Apache does not automatically do that.

> `sudo chown $USER:$USER /tmp/xdebug`

This is unlikely to be correct, as it needs to be the *Apache* user (often `www-data`) that can write to that directory, and not your shell user (which is likely just your log-in username — you can check that with `echo $USER`).

Comment: Thank you for the response. As you outlined, I had a combination of things going on. I am planning on getting to PHP & will post what I did below.

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps someone, I made two basic mistakes. Thank you @Derick

Mistake #1: My xdebug profiling directory should have been owned by `www-data`

```
sudo chown www-data /tmp/xdebug
```

Mistake #2: I forgot to restart PHP 7.2 PHP-FPM

```
sudo systemctl restart php7.2-fpm
```

So, compiled, the steps I took to get Xdebug working with PHP 7.2 PHP-FPM
(Assumes installed LAMP environment)

1 - [Install Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/docs/install) (I'm on Ubuntu)

```
sudo apt-get install php-xdebug
```

2 - Create the directory to store profiling files & give Apache ownership

```
sudo mkdir /tmp/xdebug
sudo chown www-data /tmp/xdebug
```

3 - Enable Xdebug via php.ini (you can use `phpinfo()` to determine your `.ini` file location)

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini
```

Add the following at the bottom of the .ini file (see [settings documentation](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#mode) for your needs)

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=xdebug
xdebug.output_dir = /tmp/xdebug
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.mode=develop,trace,profile
```

4 - Restart PHP-FPM & Apache

```
sudo systemctl restart php7.2-fpm
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```